# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file with jaxbUnmarshaller

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, xsd

This is a java method which unmarshalls xml file.

I looked for several problems with this error but I couldn't find an answer.

```
    @WebMethod(operationName = "List_Flights")
    public List<FlightAvailableOffers> List_Flights() {//ArrayList<String[]>

       FlightAvailableOffers flighte = new FlightAvailableOffers();
        Flights flight = new Flights();
        List<FlightAvailableOffers> bookingAvailFlights = flight.getOffersBooking();
        try {

        File file = new File("Flight_Bookings.xml");

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(FlightAvailableOffers.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        flight = (Flights)jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
                //List<FlightAvailableOffers> bookingAvailFlights = flight.getOffersBooking();

            FlightAvailableOffers booking = new FlightAvailableOffers();

            Iterator itr = bookingAvailFlights.iterator();    
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                booking = (FlightAvailableOffers) itr.next();
                bookingAvailFlights.add(booking);
            }

      } catch (JAXBException e) {
              System.out.println(e.getCause());
      }


        return bookingAvailFlights;

    }   
}
```

But when I run this  it shows this message

> "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file with
>   jaxbUnmarshaller"

Can anyone help me to get rid of this?

Comment: Can you reproduce with a small input file and show the xml input?

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/filebookings here is the xml file.

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/flightinfo this is xsd file

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in flightinfo.xsd. The **tns:** namespace is declared in the document..

**Recorded reason: UndeclaredPrefix: Cannot resolve 'tns:FlightAvailableOffers' as a QName: the prefix 'tns' is not declared**

Hint:

You  can validate your xml against xsd through online tools.

I would recommend the below one.. [XML Validation against XML Schema Document](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/)